# SQL % of data contains a value

Tags: sql

I have a Microsoft SQL table with an `organization` column and an `mi_status` column, both of which are strings.  I want to find out for each (grouped by) organization how many of the records have an mi_status of 'In Stock', how many total records there are, and then what % of the records are In Stock.

I can easily get the In Stock part via something like this:

```sql
SELECT organization, count(*)
FROM table
WHERE mi_status = 'In Stock'
GROUP BY organiztion
```

but I don't know how to also get the total rows in that same select since I've got the 'where' clause there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT organization, count(*) as total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mi_status = 'In Stock' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_instock,
       AVG(CASE WHEN mi_status = 'In Stock' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as proportion_instock
FROM table
GROUP BY organization;
```

Comment: Nice thinking with the `AVERAGE`, but you should change it to `AVG`

Comment: @Lamak Isn't that GREAT?  Gordon demonstrated this earlier this morning.  Makes me wonder how long that has been in back pocket

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  organization, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN mi_status = 'In Stock' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) In_Stock,
        COUNT(*) Total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN mi_status = 'In Stock' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100.0/COUNT(*) Percentage
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY organization;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    organization, 
    count(*), 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) as total
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    mi_status = 'In Stock'
GROUP BY 
    organization
```